# Uncaught TypeError: courses.splice is not a function

Tags: javascript

Course_id is a array which contain 1 same value as function argument

```
enter code here
function remove_course(course)
{
var courses=document.getElementsByName('course_id[]');
var courses=course.value;
var index = courses.indexOf(course_id);
if (index > -1) {
courses.splice(index, 1);
}
}
```

Comment: Read [ask] before posting questions.

Comment: `var courses` cannot hold both the element collection and `course.value` at the same time. Also note that a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName#Syntax) isn't actually an Array and does not have array methods.

Comment: Anis sadly this is an "English-only" board so you have to write your questions in a foreign language. That makes it very hard to learn this place. So try three times as hard when putting up questions. I see this is your first question. Take an extra 5 mins on the language and try and run it by a colleague to make sure you question is clear. If you do this you will get great responses and people will be very helpful. This place can be a bit "harsh" but good luck. Sure you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's basic solution, it should help you to get things done

```js
function remove_course(course) {
  //get ellements by name, it's an nodeList
  var element = document.getElementsByName('course_id[]');
  
  //get first element's value, it's a string
  var courses_raw= element[0].value;
  
  //convert string into valid JSON object
  var courses = JSON.parse(courses_raw);
  
  //courses is an array
  var index = courses.indexOf(course);
  if (index > -1) {
    
    //splice it
    courses.splice(index, 1);
    
    //set value to element
    element[0].value = JSON.stringify(courses);
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="course_id[]" value="[1,2,3]" />
<button onclick=remove_course(1)>remove 1</button>
<button onclick=remove_course(2)>remove 2</button>
<button onclick=remove_course(3)>remove 3</button>
```